# Why does a document in Word 2007 stop recognizing the mouse after the document loses focus?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open a document in Word 2007, everything works fine, I can edit, highlight text, etc.  However, the instant Word loses focus, when I focus back the document doesn't recognize anything the mouse does.

The tabbed menu at the top seems to recognize the mouse but the document itself does not.  I can scroll through via the scroll-wheel and I can type.  However, typing just shows up where the mouse cursor last was before focus was taken away.

I've tried clearing some word data registry keys.  I've also found that some Word Add-ins can cause problems.  LaserFiche is one I see mentioned a lot.  As far as I can tell I have no add-ons though.

Any ideas?  It's crazy-annoying.

**UPDATE-**
- Word is the only program that has this problem
- Typically I have Toad (Oracle DB management app), an XP virtual machine with various apps running on it, Skype, Google Talk, and maybe a handful of other programs at any given time open... Windows Media player, Outlook.
- Yes, this happens even if nothing else is running.  From a fresh restart as well.
- I'm running Vista 64 with SP1
- According to Windows Update, I have the latest of everything.  This has been happening for a couple of months now.  Just never took the time to look into because I usually never have to use word.

Comment: Have you tried using a different mouse or uninstalling/re-installing the drivers for your current mouse?

Comment: This rings a bell! I remember some very strange mouse/keyboard issues, while running Toad. There was a version, which made the mouse cursor jump around the desktop, while it was loading. Some funny things happened as well, when the main window was showing up and the panels were laying itself out.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problems when I had an overheating video card.

Is word the only program you are having problems with?

What other programs do you have open when this happens?

Does it happen even if nothing else is running?

Which version of Windows are you running?

Do you have the latest service packs and updates for both Windows and Office?

Comment: Added responses to your questions in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps resetting the Normal template? It's called Normal.dotm and is located here: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

I'm also curious: If you were to anywhere on the document and drag as if to highlight a piece of text, does the text stay un-highlighted?

Comment: I tried resetting the normal template, also highlighting would not work after the mouse stopped working.  I just installed a round of Windows updates and the issue was fixed.  As to what the issue was... beats me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a document with the same symptoms, but only the one document, so maybe the problem is not the same. Anyway, I'll present my story in case you recognise anything in common.

My document was an order form with complex tables and calculated fields.
(These seem like likely candidates but turned out *not* to be a problem)

When I refocussed the document I noticed that the mouse seemed to be in image/object selection mode (with an arrow pointer instead of a cursor) but would not select anything nor go back to a cursor. There was only one image in the document, I deleted it and the problem went away. I re-added the same image back in the same place and everything continued to work fine.

The root of this may have been that the document was originally made in Word 2003 and converted to Word 2007 format.